# Unable to access 'numpy.typing' directly for static typing in NumPy 1.24.3

Tags: python, numpy, dependencies

I'm trying to use the ArrayLike type from the numpy.typing module for static typing. I am using NumPy version 1.24.3.

When I import ArrayLike directly from numpy.typing, everything works as expected:

```
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

def myfun(a: ArrayLike):
   pass
```

However, if I try to import numpy as np and then use np.typing.ArrayLike, I get an AttributeError.

With:

```
import numpy

def myfun(a: numpy.typing.ArrayLike):
   pass
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 320, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typing'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.
I tried it on my local machine and in an online python interpreter with the same result.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single Package like numpy, there are subpackages like typing. the file structure is similar to:

```
numpy/
    __init__.py
    ...
    typing/
        ...
        __init__.py
        ...
```

By using:

```
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
```

you are importing the subpackage 'typing' from package 'numpy' and using the attribute ArrayLike.
However, this:

```
import numpy
numpy.typing.ArrayLike
```

only imports the numpy package. The second line treats "typing" as a value exported by numpy. However, "typing" is a subpackage.
Therefore, it results in error.

Comment: So there is no way around also importing numpy.typing separately? Do I understand correctly that importing a package does not import subpackages and subpackages cannot be referenced unless imported themselves?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly that importing a package would not import subpackages.

Comment: You have to import subpackages separately in order to use them.

Comment: for more info, you can see the docs- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: You have to read the package's documentation.  `numpy` loads most of the package by default, but has a small number of subpackages that require explicit importing.  `typing` is a relatively new subpackage, and not required by most users, so it requires its own import.  `scipy` consists of many independent subpackages, so most of those require special imports.  It all depends, and should be well documented.

Comment: I am still new to python and as you said, I never had to import anything more specific with numpy, since it loads most of the package, which confused me with typing. Thank you!